# Keyword normalizer not applied on document

Tags: elasticsearch, keyword, lowercase

I'm using Elasticsearch 6.8
here is my mapping

```json
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "my_index_*"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 3,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "lower_ascii_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      },
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [],
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "audit_conformity": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {
        "country": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
        },
[…]
```

Then I post a document with this body

```json
{
  "_source": {
    "company_id": "a813bec1-f9f3-44c7-96ac-11157f64b79b",
    "country": "MX",
    "user_entity_id": "1"
  }
}
```

When I search for the document, the country is still capitalized

```
GET /my_index_country/_search
```

I get

```json
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index_country",
        "_type": "my_index",
        "_id": "LOT0fYIBCNP9gFG_7cet",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "_source": {
            "company_id": "a813bec1-f9f3-44c7-96ac-11157f64b79b",
            "country": "MX",
            "user_entity_id": "1",
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do nothing wrong, but normalizers (and analyzer alike) will never modify your **source document**, only whatever is indexed from it.

This means that the source document keeps holding `MX` but underneath `mx` will be indexed for the `country` field.

If you want to lowercase the country field, you should use an ingest pipeline with a `lowercase` processor instead which will modify your source document before indexing it:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/lowercase-pipiline
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "lowercase": {
        "field": "country"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then use it when indexing your documents:

```
PUT my_index_country/my_index/LOT0fYIBCNP9gFG_7cet?pipeline=lowercase-pipeline
{
    "company_id": "a813bec1-f9f3-44c7-96ac-11157f64b79b",
    "country": "MX",
    "user_entity_id": "1",
}

GET my_index_country/my_index/LOT0fYIBCNP9gFG_7cet

Result =>
{
    "company_id": "a813bec1-f9f3-44c7-96ac-11157f64b79b",
    "country": "mx",
    "user_entity_id": "1",
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I thought it wasn't working because I made a mistake while indexing my document (I put all the fields in a `_source` node), so my query didn't find any result. I'll take a look at that pipeline, I might implement it.